# Swap canvas element with another table cells value

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html-table, swap

I have a 3x3 HTML table with each element storing a separate `<canvas>` element
There is one cell in the table containing `text` instead of a `<canvas>`
When a cell containing an image is clicked and the cell to its right contains text, I'm trying to swap that cell's canvas with the text stored in the neighbouring cell.
With the following code every time I click a cell, the canvas element disappears and only swaps the text, leaving the cell on the right no longer containing text or a `<canvas>`
I tried accessing the canvas using `("#blankCell").html()` but it does not work .. anybody know how to access this content for swapping of values?
I created a simplified jsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/dbMnM/1/

```
$(function () {

    var $tbl = $('<table border="1">').attr('id', 'grid');
    var $tbody = $('<tbody>').attr('id', 'tableBody');
    var tileCount = 0;
            var rowCount = $("#numOfPieces").val();

    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {

        var trow = $("<tr>").attr('id', 'row' + i); // New row

        for (var j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {

            $cell.append(canvasArray[tileCount]); // Each data cell contains separate canvas element
            $cell.appendTo(trow); 
            tileCount++;
        }

        trow.appendTo($tbody);
    }

    $tbl.append($tbody);
    $('table').remove(); // removes previous table if it existed
    $('body').append($tbl);
});

$('#grid tr:nth-child(2) td:last').prev().text("empty");
$('#grid tr:nth-child(2) td:last').prev().attr('id', 'blankCell');
```

Listens for clicks ..

```
   $('body').on('click', '#grid td', function(e) {

    var $this = $(this);
    if ($(this).closest('td').next("#blankCell").length){

        blank = $(this).closest('td').next("#blankCell");

        if (blank.length) {
            //alert('blank to the right');
            $this.before(blank);
        }
        $(this).attr('id', 'blankCell');
        $(this).closest('td').next("#blankCell").attr('id', 'piece');

    }
```

Appreciate any help!

Instead of using canvas elements for swapping, it now only has text.
The goal is if a user selects a cell beside the `blankCell` I would like to swap that cell with the `blankCell`, if the user selects a cell not beside `blankCell` I would like nothing to happen.
Only concerned with left and right detection for now.

Comment: Do not execute `$("#numOfPieces").val()` in each loop turn's condition. Assign it once to a variable and then use that. Or do you expect it to change?

Comment: Your right, i've updated condition to use a variable instead `rowCount` .. it will not change value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it simple and just exchange the whole table cells, not their contents or content strings and attributes:

```
$('#grid').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        blank = $this.next("#blankCell");
    if (blank.length) {
        //alert('blank to the right');
        $this.before(blank);
    }
});
```

OK, some more complicated code for checking the position included:

```
var empty = $("#empty").get(0);
$('#grid').on('click', 'td', function(e) {
    if (!empty || this == empty) return; // abort, abort!

    var currow = this.parentNode,
        emptyrow = empty.parentNode;
    var cx = this.cellIndex,
        cy = currow.rowIndex,
        ex = empty.cellIndex,
        ey = emptyrow.rowIndex;
    if (cx==ex && Math.abs(cy-ey)==1 || cy==ey && Math.abs(cx-ex)==1) {
        // empty and this are next to each other in the grid
        var afterempty = empty.nextSibling,
            afterthis = this.nextSibling;
        currow.insertBefore(empty, afterthis);
        emptyrow.insertBefore(this, afterempty);
    }
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/dbMnM/2/)

Comment: This works perfectly for right and left swaps! do you know how I could swap the blank cell with the cell below? I use this code to determine if cell clicked is below the blank one .. `if ($(this).parent().prev().children("#blankCell").index() == $(this).index())`

Comment: Uh, no idea how to do that best with jQuery. Plain [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore) sound easier to me for doing it: `var after = blank.nextSibling, parent = blank.parentNode; this.parentNode.insertBefore(blank, this); parent.insertBefore(this; after);`

Comment: unfortunately that doesnt work when `blank` is set to `$(this).parent().prev().children("#blankCell")`, i will keep looking, thanks for your answer!

Comment: `blank` would need to be a native DOM node of course, not a jQuery element: `var blank = document.getElementById("blank")`, or use jQuery [`.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore)

Comment: yeah that makes sense, i can now swap cells above and below .. thanks for your help!

Comment: I found issue with the code, if a user selects a cell not beside `blankCell` it still swaps the cells, i only want the swap to occur if the neighbouring cell is blank

Comment: @bobbyrne01: I never said it would not. You will need to check the conditions yourself before calling the code.